How to mock static method and their returned result in NodeJS + Typescript?
I am learning to write the unit test cases for NodeJS + Typescript using Jest. Currently, I have a very simple Express application, wherein the repository (that connects with MongoDB via a MongoConfig custom class) layer I have a few methods to insert/select the data. Below are two of them:
  export default class MyRepository {
    ...
    private _getCollection(collectionName: string): Collection {
      let collection = this._collections[collectionName];
      if (!collection) {
        collection = MongoConfig.getDatabase().collection(collectionName);
        this._collections[collectionName] = collection;
      }
      return collection;
    }

    public async insert(collectionName: string, dataToSave: any): Promise<void> {
      let collection = this._getCollection(collectionName);
      await collection.insertOne(dataToSave);
    }
    ...
  }

Here I want to mock MongoConfig.getDatabase().collection(<any string>) method call in _getCollection(..) method and return the mocked Collection object. How can this be achieved using Jest?
Also, it would be great if you could explain how we can test insert(..) method. Should we just check whether await collection.insertOne(dataToSave) is invoked in that method?

It's not shown what MongoConfig  is and where it comes from, so nothing can be suggested on how it could be mocked. Considering that you're familiar with Jest mocking, what did you try and what did not work?

MongoConfig is a simple class to connect to MongoDB database and few methods that return MongoClient and Db to be used in another classes wherever required.


Import MongoConfig in your test file
In your test create an object with properties that are mock function.
Create a mock function collection that returns the object
Use jest.spyOn to mock MongoConfig.getDatabase to have it return the mock collection
Assert on the relevant on methods

import { MongoConfig } from 'mongodb' // Substitute with the proper import

const collectionMethods = {
  insertOne: jest.fn(async () => {})
}
const collection = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(collectionMethods);
jest.spyOn(MongoConfig, 'getDatabase').mockReturnValue(collection);

// Clear all mocks

describe('insert', () => {
  it('works', async () => {
    const collectionName = 'foo';
    const dataToSave = {};
    const repo = new MyRepository();
    await repo.insert(collectionName, dataToSave);
    expect(collection).toHaveBeenCalledWith(collectionName);
    expect(collectionMethods.insertOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith(dataToSave);
  })
})

If you're going to repeat this pattern in multiple test files, consider creating a manual mock for your mongodb driver that exports the mock MongoConfig

Thanks @Brother58697, your answer paved a path for me. I made a few changes in your solution and my test case started working (I will post that soon for others to refer). But just one thing, what if we want to use jest.mock instead of jest.spyOn? How can we use that?

You have to set it up like in the documentation. The catch is that mocks are hoisted so you can't create variables and pass them into the mock factory to assert on later. You have to assert on the imported variable. So to reach your collection object, you have to call MongoConfig.getDatabase(), which you should have mocked into returning the mock collection instance

Yes, so that's what I was thinking, but confused on how we can mock MongoConfig.getDatabase() instead of Spying on it?

You mock the whole module, where you return an object with MongoConfig that has methods that return the mocks. Take a look at the documentation and search around for how to mock classes and modules. You got this!

@JigneshM.Khatri The difference between jest.mock and jest.spyOn is that the former mocks a module and the latter spies OR mocks a method. It's not like spyOn can only spy. It creates jest spy function which can do whatever you need it. This is what the answer shows. If you can get direct access to the same MongoConfig object as used in tested unit, you don't need jest.mock

Thanks, @Brother58697 and Estus Flask for the clarifications and solution. It worked for me.
